# An unwanted emoji is showing up in Slack messages sent through to webhook

Tags: php, curl, webhooks, slack, slack-api

I've searched everywhere to find someone else with this issue but couldn't find anything.

The issue is I am trying to send a message from a php script to my slack channel with the Shopify order number. It's working as it should apart from one thing, It's adding a Red Square emoji in the messages and I can't figure out why.

This is what the message comes through as:

> **red square that shouldn't be there**
>   [image]

And this is the code I'm using to send the slack message:

```
  // Create a constant to store your Slack URL
  define('SLACK_WEBHOOK', 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/x/x/eActr8MIhT0SIyKuGGwR0ScU');
  // Make your message
  $message = array('payload' => json_encode(array('text' => 'Order '.$shopify_order['name'].' has been sent to Embroidery Works' )));
  // Use curl to send your message
  $c = curl_init(SLACK_WEBHOOK);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message);
  curl_exec($c);
  curl_close($c);
```

Comment: Could it be "trash" text due to not being encoded properly, eg not UTF-8?

Comment: Hmm possibly, ill have a look at how to confirm that and get back, thanks!

Comment: Can you copy and paste the entire message here?

Comment: Worth nothing: `#BA1242` is a dark-red color. You'll often see it on programmer forums when describing CSS.  http://www.color-hex.com/color/ba1242

Comment: Haha, now i feel silly! Yea, looks like slack automatically adds a preview for hex colors. Thanks @Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Worth nothing: #BA1242 is a dark-red color. You'll often see it on programmer forums when describing CSS. color-hex.com/color/ba1242 – @Chris*

Slack automatically posts previews of hex colours as Chris (Thanks!) pointed out. Just turns out that this particular store codes match hex colors.

Comment: If it's helpful, you can disable the hex color preview setting in your Slack preferences: https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/213893898-Change-your-message-display-settings

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to display the message without that hex code in slack. I mean when the message is entered with hex code in typing area and as soon as the message is posted, only the red squealed should be displayed.
Something similar to use of emoji